# Does react-native-fast-image cache images that were loaded with require in src

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

Does the React Native library "React Native Fast Image" (https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) have any difference in behavior if we use "require()" instead of "{uri:}"?

(I'm confused as "{uri:}" is the only way mentioned in the docs)

Comment: They have an issue open which explains how they are planning to go about having local image support, as far as I can tell they have the code merged on master so shouldnt take too long for them to release it. https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/pull/205

Comment: Thanks, @NemiShah.. if posted as an answer I can accept..

Comment: Moved it as an answer so it can help someone else wondering the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have an issue open which explains how they are planning to go about having local image support, as far as I can tell they have the code merged on master so shouldnt take too long for them to release it.

[Github Issue](http://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/pull/205)